App Installed and Opened on TestFlight Shows an Empty White Screen
When I install and open my React Native iOS app on my iPhone device using the TestFlight app, it shows an empty white screen. But, it works fine on my XCode Simulator and my iPhone device when run through XCode on both debug or release modes. What could be the reason for getting an empty white screen when running my app on TestFlight? Blank Screen on TestFlight
I have already added the assets folder, main.jsbundle, Images.xcassets to the "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases tab on XCode which made it run on XCode without any issue but, not on TestFlight.
Edit: I rendered a text in the Login page and it appeared when testing on TestFlight. But, the below line throws an error "Unknown WebAuth error".
let tokens = await azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({ scope: 'openid profile User.Read Mail.Read' });
My AzureAuth objects looks like below. Note: The actual values are removed.
const azureAuth = new AzureAuth({
issuer: issuer,
clientId: CLIENT_ID,
redirectUri: redirectUri,
scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
additionalParameters: {},
serviceConfiguration: {
authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint,
tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint,
revocationEndpoint: revocationEndpoint,
}
});
The issue could be with the redirectUri in the AzureAuth object. I tried the registered URL in the Azure AD (URL which goes {bundle identifier}://{bundle identifier}/ios/callback) but, it doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct format to add it? And should it start with https?
However, the android APK works without any issue even without the redirectUri. What could be the issue with the iOS app?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I know it might sound like a "generic" answer, but trust me, sometimes you just need to double-check even the most common issues. Why? Because I'm a RN programmer too :)
I suggest compiling a "release" version locally, trying to explore logs and output file. Also, if you can, try to do the same with Android and see if the problem is on both platforms or only on iOS. If you cannot upload the Android in Play Console, just do the plain release apk, if possibile.
Check if you don't have any conditions in your code (like __DEV__) that could potentially stop something from rendering. Also, please note if on your debug version some warnings/errors are popping up in RN console and iOS console.
Is your compiling process for TestFlight different from the local one? Make sure the steps are the same.
As the last hope, if you have spare time, try to place only a View + Text inside the root of your app: no providers, no other components. Then compile for TestFlight. If those render, maybe the problems is one of your components crashing and preventing the app from launching. Try to search for it and understand why. Same thing with any libraries/plugins you might have added.
Ah, right. Check for updates. Maybe you have an "old" version of RN or one of the dependencies. RN is kinda fragile from this point of view, one thing can break everything and you cannot know what breaks it.
